# Installing Kinetic on Ubuntu 17.04: possible? Known issues?

Tags: ros, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to this but I saw this: "ROS Kinetic ONLY supports Wily (Ubuntu 15.10), Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) and Jessie (Debian 8) for debian packages."
in here:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

So wondering if there's any known problems In should be aware of. Thanks!     : ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262187/installing-kinetic-on-ubuntu-17.04:-possible?-known-issues?/) by [electron spectrum](https://answers.ros.org/users/30472/electron-spectrum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-21**:
I've changed the title of your question to more accurately reflect what your question is -- and also to make it slightly more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Known problems (already during installation):

- no binary packages available (the buildfarm doesn't build them for 17.04, as is stated on the install wiki page)
- source build required, but:

  - not all dependencies may be available on 17.04 (pkgs might have been renamed / not released / something else)
  - dependencies are no longer compatible (ie: newer Boost versions with deprecated / removed / changed functionality, etc)

Apart from that: not many people will have run ROS on this version of Ubuntu, so the part of the community that could help you is probably also small.

---

Edit: ROS Lunar *is* available for Ubuntu 17.04 (see [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019)), so you could try that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-21**:
Note that these are not really "known problems" in the traditional sense: these are not issues that have been identified while *running* ROS on 17.04, but is more a speculation of what you will probably run into when/if trying to get ROS to run on unsupported OS releases.